# button.Button class error:'button_list not defined'..... :( using replit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am following a tutorial online creating a map editor for a platform game and my import button feature is not working, showing error 'button_list not defined' but I can not see why this is as I defined it as empty list already? I have the following code for the button class.

```py
import pygame
import button

def button():
    button_list = []
    button_col = 0
    button_row = 0
    for i in range(len(img_list)):
        tile_button = button.Button(SCREEN_WIDTH + (75 * button_col) + 50, 75 * button_row + 50, img_list[i], 1)
        button_list.append(tile_button)
        button_col += 1
        if button_col == 3:
            button_row += 1
            button_col = 0
```

This has no errors and runs OK, (nothing on screen of course) but when I draw it with the following code the error occurs.

```py
for i in button_list:
    i.draw(screen)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) if you want to define a variable in the global namespace within a function:

```py
def button():
    global button_list 

    button_list = []

    button_col = 0
    button_row = 0
    for i in range(len(img_list)):
        # [...]
```

```py
button()
for i in button_list:
    i.draw(screen)
```

---

Alternatively you can define `button_list` in global namespace:

```py
button_list = []

def button():
    button_col = 0
    button_row = 0
    for i in range(len(img_list)):
        tile_button = button.Button(SCREEN_WIDTH + (75 * button_col) + 50, 75 * button_row + 50, img_list[i], 1)
        button_list.append(tile_button)
        button_col += 1
        if button_col == 3:
            button_row += 1
            button_col = 0
```